# Python object list append issue

Tags: python, list

I tried object append to list then print it.

customer.py

```
class Customer:
def __init__(self,id,name,address,active,created):
    self.id=id
    self.name=name
    self.address=address
    self.active=active
    self.created=created
```

main.py

```
import customer
cList=list()

for x in range(5,10):
    c=customer.Customer("","c"+str(x)+" name","c"+str(x)+" adress","","")
    cList.append({c.name, c.address})

for a in cList:
    print(a)
```

Expected Output

> {'c5 name', 'c5 adress'}
>   
> {'c6 name', 'c6 adress'}
>   
> {'c7 name', 'c7 adress'}
>   
> {'c8 name', 'c8 adress'}
>   
> {'c9 name', 'c9 adress'}

Real Output

> {'c5 name', 'c5 adress'}
>   
> {'c6 adress', 'c6 name'}
>   
> {'c7 adress', 'c7 name'}
>   
> {'c8 adress', 'c8 name'}
>   
> {'c9 name', 'c9 adress'}

when I run code each time it gives me different result. I will use this list for insert data to MySQL so order of this list important. First value of object should be name property.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What did you expect `{c.name, c.address}` to do exactly?

Comment: @deceze It is my error. I tried to create object array. Thus I could reach each element with its property.

Comment: like this    cList.append({"name":c.name, "address":c.address})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is a list of sets which are unordered, use lists or tuples instead

```
cList.append({c.name, c.address})
```

should be (either)

```
cList.append((c.name, c.address))
cList.append([c.name, c.address])
```